# Setting content type "application/pdf" in Groovy RESTClient / HTTPBuilder

Tags: rest, groovy, content-type, httpbuilder

I'm using Groovy's RESTClient/HTTPBuilder library to send GET and POST requests to a webservice. One resource requires a PDF with content type `application/pdf`. The response will be an XML.

Request --> POST application/pdf
Response <-- application/xml

I have tried the following:

```
def client = new RESTClient(url)
client.post(
  uri: url,
  body: new File('C:/temp/test.pdf').bytes,
  requestContentType: 'application/pdf'
)

def client = new RESTClient(url)
client.setContentType('application/pdf')
client.post(
  uri: url,
  body: new File('C:/temp/test.pdf').bytes,
)
```

Both variants produce:

> No encoder found for request content type application/pdf

As far as I have understood the library doesn't support `application/pdf` by default.

How can I implement the above?

**Update from 2015-10-15 after answer by @opal**

The following code snippet at least puts the PDF into the request body. However I cannot see the `Content-type: application/pdf` in the POST request. Also the server rejects the request with "Invalid mime type".

```
client.encoder.putAt('application/pdf', new MethodClosure(this, 'encodePDF'))
response = client.post(
  uri: url,
  body: new File('C:/temp/test.pdf'),
  requestContentType: 'application/pdf'
)

HttpEntity encodePDF(File pdf) {
  new FileEntity(pdf)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to define a custom encoder. Follow the (incomplete) example below:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.MethodClosure
import org.apache.http.entity.FileEntity

//this part adds a special encoder    
def client = new RESTClient('some host')
client.encoder.putAt('application/pdf', new MethodClosure(this, 'encodePDF'))

//here is the method for the encoder added above
HttpEntity encodePDF(File pdf) {
    new FileEntity(pdf)
}
```

Please try the example above and let me know if it worked.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Maybe I got something wrong? Here's my code: [link](http://pastebin.com/6qERsNtJ)  Exception: `No signature of method: encodePDF() is applicable for argument types: (org.apache.http.entity.FileEntity)`

Comment: Pass a File itself, not FileEntity.

Comment: Sorry, maybe it's too late in the evening :) Would you mind adding that to your code above?

Comment: It seems as if I can't see the wood for the trees. [Here is my code](http://pastebin.com/6qERsNtJ) and I can't find any major differences to yours. However I get the exception.

Comment: Instead of `body: encodePDF(new File('C:/temp/test.pdf')),` it should be: `body: new File('C:/temp/test.pdf'),`

Comment: Needed to add the `headers` map to the request:  `response = client.post(
      uri: url,
      headers: [ 'Content-Type': 'application/pdf' ],
      body: new File('C:/temp/test.pdf'),
      requestContentType: 'application/pdf'
    )`